# Multiplication of a vector with submatrices is slow

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a tall matrix (the example below is 10000-by-3000) and I want to take inner products with a subset of its rows (e.g., 500 rows). This is repeated with different, randomly chosen rows for many times (100 times in the example, but in reality many more times). It turns out that the indexing `A(sub,:)` is rather slow. In my example, it is better to multiply the full matrix `A` (i.e., 10000 rows) instead of selectively choosing and multiplying the 500 that are actually needed.

The random generation of the row indices (`sub = randperm(10000);` `sub = sub(1:500);`) is cheap computationally; I put it in both loops in order to be fair.

```
A=randn(10000,3000);
g=zeros(10000,1);

tic
for i=1:100
    sub = randperm(10000); sub = sub(1:500);
    b=randn(3000,1);
    g(sub) = g(sub) + A(sub,:)*b;
end
toc
% elapsed time is 1.58 sec

tic
for i=1:100
    sub = randperm(10000); sub = sub(1:500);
    b=randn(3000,1);
    g = g + A*b;
end
toc
% elapsed time is 1.28 sec
```

The question is: is there a way to speed up things when only a subset of rows are actually needed?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but `sub = randperm(10000); sub = sub(1:500);` is the same as just `sub = randperm(10000,500);`. Might save you a microsecond :/

Comment: Though not exactly your question, you might find this [recent blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/05/04/recent-question-about-speed-with-subarray-calculations/) from the MathWorks interesting. Another reason for the slowdown when indexing is that `A` needs to "evaluate" `sub` in a manner akin to what a function does before proceeding.

Comment: `randperm` usage has changed with matlab versions so the statements here are legacy compatible

Comment: Did not see the reduction Yannisdoc observed using the full matrix product (but the results were very similar).

Comment: Did my answer help [solve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)? Were you able to speed things up on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying across the rows instead of the columns. This may require you to rearrange your data or apply a scalar transpose (`.'`)or two, but as that is the native form of the arrays you may get a surprising speedup. For example, swapping the dimensions of `A` and `g`:

```
A = randn(3000,10000);
g = zeros(1,10000);

tic
for i = 1:100
    sub = randperm(10000,500);  % Taking @Dan's suggestion
    b = randn(1,3000);          % b is now a row vector
    g(sub) = g(sub)+b*A(:,sub); % multiply across rows instead
end
toc
```

You can transpose the output if need be. On my computer this is over 50% faster than your first case.

I believe at least one of the underlying reasons for this is that that BLAS/LAPACK can use [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) in this case.

Comment: Fantastic result. On my machine the speed improvement is x10.